# Declare an advance regex pattern in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I wanted to remove all the non alphanumeric characters from my string, to do that I used this :

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]");
string newString = rgx.Replace(oldString, "");
```

However, I have now a new constrainst which is to keep in addition to the alphanumeric characters, the apostroph character "`'`";

Example : For this string "`abcd1*%'`", I would like to get "`abcd1'`".

Edit : Thanks Alex K for your solution, it's working. I am now trying to make this regex more complex, I would like now to not keep all the apostrop character "'", but only the apostroph character surrounded by alphanumeric characters "x'x";

Example : For this string "`abc'd1*%'`", I would like to get "`abc'd1`".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add it to the character class `[^a-zA-Z0-9' -]` as it contain a list of characters that will *not* be removed.

Also better to use the static `Regex.Replace()` without the need to create an instance.

Comment: Thanks it's working, I have edited my post to ask for an evolution.